# Preprocessor Conditionals

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a define which changes values at some point in the code be used in a conditional. Basically something like this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////// SomeFile.cpp
#define SHUTDOWN false

while(window->isOpen())
{
    if(SHUTDOWN)
        window->close();
    // Rest of the main loop
}

//////////////////////////////////////////// SomeOtherFile.cpp

if(Escape.isPressed())
{
    #undef SHUTDOWN
    #define SHUTDOWN true
}
```

Thus causing the app to close. If it's not, would having a function like

```
RenderWindow* getWindow()
{
    return window;
}
```

and then calling

```
if(Escape.isPressed())
    getWindow()->close();
```

The best way to do it? I'd rather not go that route because the classes that are calling the key event are members of the class controlling the main loop and the window, so I'd have to set pointers to the containing class in the smaller classes to call getWindow() and it just seems like a more complicated method. But if I can't do it with preprocessor directives I'll just have to use pointers to the parent class.

Comment: Why using `define` after all (instead of a normal variable)? This is preprocessor directive, it's executed only once at compile time and NOT at runtime.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood preprocessor directives.  They are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Where would the normal variable be so that I can access it from the scope of these classes? The classes calling the event are not really even aware of the parents existence. In fact when they're instantiated they go into a vector inside a class which is a member of the overall class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the use of preprocessor symbols.  Think of preprocessor code as separate code that is entangled with your c/c++ code.  At compile time the preprocessor code executed and that execution results in source code which the compiler then coverts into binary.  You can't use preprocessor symbols at runtime because they do not exist (they were compiled away).  It appears you are might want to use a globally scoped variable in what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

A pre-processor conditional is only condition prior during the first, pre-processing, phase of compilation.

Once that phase of compilation has been completed, the macro (the #define value) is effectively replaced instanations.

When you write

```
if (SHUTDOWN)
```

then what the compiler sees is the value of "SHUTDOWN" at the time that pre-processing finished and compilation proper begin. So

```
#define SHUTDOWN true
if (SHUTDOWN)
```

compiles to

```
if (true)
```

whereas

```
#define SHUTDOWN

if (SHUTDOWN)
```

failes to compile, as

```
if ()
```

If you were to #define SHUTDOWN to resolve to a variable, then yes, this is absolutely possible, because variables can change at run time. But constants don't.